# Set UICulture for subfolder in web application

Tags: asp.net, culture, subdirectory, uiculture

I have the following code in my Global.asax file:

```
Protected Sub Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Language"))
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Language"))
End Sub
```

This sets the `UICulture` and `Culture` to a value defined in the web.config `AppSettings`.

This therefore changes date formatting text throughout the application.

However, my application has a subfolder, `/Admin`. If the culture is set to `es` (Spanish), then I still need the admin folder to be `en` (English).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I've thought of (but I'm not sure it's the best, so open to other ideas), is to override the `Culture` and `UICulture` in my Admin sections MasterPage, which every web form calls from:

```
Sub Page_Init()
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en")
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en")
End Sub
```